# Show camera on iOS app with most of the screen blur

Tags: ios, swift, camera, qr-code

I want to create an iOS app that is able to scan QR codes through it. I have been able to add the logic that scans the code itself, but I am having issues with the UI of this screen. What I want to achieve is showing the camera display on a blurry mode, and having a small square in the center of the screen that actually shows what the camera is *seeing*.

Let's get to some code:

```
class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
            let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice) else {
                return
        }

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.addInput(deviceInput)

        let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)
        captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]

        guard let captureSession = captureSession else { return }
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width / 2 - 80, y: view.frame.height / 2 - 80, width: 160, height: 160)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        captureSession.startRunning()

    }
}
```

This code allows me to present a screen with an orange background, which has a square of 160x160 in the middle of its screen that will display the camera searching for QR codes. [It looks like this on a device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi7Ce.png)

Then, I updated the code so that the `previewLayer.frame` takes the whole screen and and I can add a blue effect:

```
//      previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width / 2 - 80, y: view.frame.height / 2 - 80, width: 160, height: 160)  
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds

        let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
        blurView.frame = self.view.bounds
        blurView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(blurView)
```

[This is how it looks on the second version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoOpR.png).

My question is: how can I achieve a mixture of both? Having the entire screen showing a blur view of the camera output, while the center of the screen presents a square with a clear view of what the camera can scan? [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szTrM.jpg)

Comment: I think you can use 2 preview layers. First one can be the big blurry one and the second one a small square at the centre above the first one.

Comment: I've tried doing such thing @KauthamKrishna, but ended up having only the blur one. Even if I used two different captureSessions. Do you have any code snippet?